# Join two tables (users and userpoints_total)

Tags: 7, database

I'm working with [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce), and I am currently developing a new module that displays the best customers that have a maximum points in a single block.

I want to do a join between the two tables (users and userpoints_total)

```
$query = db_select('users', 'u')
  ->fields('u',array('name','uid'));
$query->join('userpoints_total', 't', 't.uid = u.uid');
$results = $query->execute();
```

That works but in the block views I can't see anything. This is the code:

```
    function best_client_block_view($delta = '') {
      switch ($delta) {
        case 'best_client':
          $block['subject'] = t('Les meilleures Clients Chez nous');
          if (user_access('access content')) {
            // Use our custom function to retrieve data.
            $result = best_client_contents();
            // Array to contain items for the block to render.
            $items = array();
            // Iterate over the resultset and format as links.
        if (is_array($result) || is_object($result))
            {
            foreach ($result as $node) {

              $items[] = array(
                'data' => t($node->name),

              ); 
            }
        }
           // No content in the last week.
            if (empty($items)) {
              $block['content'] = t('No user available.');  
            } 
            else {
              // Pass data through theme function.
              $block['content'] = theme('item_list', array(
                'items' => $items));
            }
          }
        return $block;
      }

    }
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: Would you be interested in a Views based answer to create such block? I.e. based on user points (ranking), and similar to the block you can see [here](http://drupal.placeto.be/answers/rankings/reputation), in the left column with block title "Top Users".

Answer (score 1):

You don't call a result set method on your query. Try `$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();` and have a look at the results via devel or something similar.

I believe that `block['content']` defaults to markup but theme functions return HTML strings not renderable arrays so you could try to use the #markup key to make them render.

```
$block['content']['#markup'] = theme('item_list', array('items' => $items));
```

Or use the theme as a part of the render array.

```
$block['content'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'item_list', 
  '#type' => 'ul', 
  '#items' => $items
)
```

Comment: but he tell always << no users avaible >> i can't understand , my query is correct, can you give me a solution?

Comment: Hmm, updated answer to adres another possible issue. Could you post your entire query @SeifBh and and show us the content of the result?

Comment: @SurangaPanagamuwaGamage Thankyou for your answer, the same thing , i always see << no users avaible >> , and this is my query

Comment: function best_client_contents() {

$max_num = variable_get('best_client_max', 3);


$query=db_select('users','us');
      
$query->join('userpoints_total','up','us.uid = up.uid');
       
$query->condition('us.uid','1')
                       ->fields('us',array('name','uid'))
                       ->fields('up',array('uid','points'));
       

$results = $query->execute()->fetchAll();

     }

Comment: Ah I see, if you're not going to use the items as render arrays you don't need to use `data` (wich I believe expects a render array), try using `$items[] = t($node->name)` directly

Comment: without foreach ?

Comment: no in the foreach, replace               
`$items[] = array('data' => t($node->name),); ` with `$items[] = t($node->name);`

Comment: dosen't work man !

Comment: the same message << no user avaible >> with error : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() dans best_client_block_view()

Comment: And you're sure your query returns a result? Use print_r or some devel function to print out the $result

Comment: yes i test that in the  function best_client_contents() like that foreach($result as $node){print $node->name}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24581/discussion-between-seifbh-and-suranga-panagamuwa-gamage).

Comment: show us a print_r of the result variable then. Because I can't see any reason why it wouldn't work apart from that the result set is somehow not a valid array of objects...

Comment: where i put the print_r ? in the hook_block_view() or where ?

Comment: this is the result of print: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => SeifEddineBh [uid] => 1 [up_uid] => 1 [points] => 3670 ) )

Comment: Warning : Invalid argument supplied for foreach() dans best_client_block_view()